# regex from grandparent folder name

Tags: bash, grep, regular-expression

I have a path like this `C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Photos-or\3-PRO\3-1-CR\CR-RESTS\LES-COQS\1920x500` and I'd like a regex to match the grandparent folder which, in this case, is `LES-COQS`.

I've tried:

```
echo "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Photos-or\3-PRO\3-1-CR\CR-RESTS\LES-COQS\1920x500" | grep -i "[a-zA-Z0-9-]*\\\[0-9a-z]*$"
```

Should I use a lookahead/lookbehind ? Or is there a simpler way ?

Thanks

Comment: That doesn't look like a path. Path components are `/` separated on Unix. Assuming you mean a MS-DOS path, I don't see `LESCOQS` in it, only `LES-COQS` which would be the directory containing the `1920x500` file, not its grandparent by any meaning of grandparent. Also, it's not clear what you mean by *matching* here. What's the output you're expecting?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I would assume that `1920x500` is itself a directory and thus a "parent" of some unspecified file. Louis, is that right?

Comment: it's a windows path, and I need a pure regex solution.

Comment: @TooTea yes right, the 1920x500 is the parent of some file indeed.

Comment: wrt `I need a pure regex solution` - so this is homework, right? Otherwise you wouldn't use a regexp for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to extract the penultimate item from the path. Here are a few with a mix of solution approaches

```
p='C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Photos-or\3-PRO\3-1-CR\CR-RESTS\LES-COQS\1920x500'

echo "$p" | grep -oP '.*\\\K[^\\]*(?=\\[^\\]+)'     # PCRE
echo "$p" | sed 's!^.*\\\([^\\]*\)\\[^\\]*$!\1!'    # RE

echo "$p" | awk -F'\\' '{print $(NF-1)}'            # Awk

IFS='\\' ps=($p); echo "${ps[-2]}"                  # Shell (bash)
px="${p%\\*}"; echo "${px##*\\}"                    # Shell
```

The expressions are much harder to read due to each backslash in the Windows folder path having to be matched by a double backslash in each RE pattern. (In fact, I worked on a couple of these by replacing `\` with `/` throughout.)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to output the second-last component of that MS-DOS-style path, you could do:

```
msdos_path='C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Photos-or\3-PRO\3-1-CR\CR-RESTS\LES-COQS\1920x500'
expr "\\$msdos_path" : '.*\\\(.*\)\\.*'
```

Which here would output `LES-COQS`.

Comment: $ echo "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Photos-originals\3-PROFESSSIONELS\3-1-CHR\CHR-RESTAURANTS\LESFRANGINS\1920x500" | grep -i '(.*\)\\.*'
returns the whole string. This doesn't work.

Comment: @Louis, `grep` is the tool to print the lines that match a regexp (that's named after the `g/re/p` command in `ed`) while here you want to *extract* a part of a string (which as it it's a path could be made of several lines), and so `expr` is a better tool for the task.

Answer (score 1):

May be this will help you to get the expected result

```
#!/bin/bash
# GNU bash, version 4.4.20
echo "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Photos-or\3-PRO\3-1-CR\CR-RESTS\LES-COQS\1920x500" | rev | awk -F'\' '{ print $2 }' | rev
```

**Output :**

```
LES-COQS
```

Tested on : https://rextester.com/l/bash_online_compiler

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed with extended regular expression and the substitution command:

```
$ echo "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Photos-or\3-PRO\3-1-CR\CR-RESTS\LES-COQS\1920x500" | sed -E 's/(.*\\)([^\\]+)(\\[^\\]+)/\2/'
LES-COQS
```